# How can I login to telegram with string session?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have a telegram string session. How can I use that to login on https://web.telegram.org/k/ or telegram App.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use telethon , you can do like this:

```
string = '1aaNk8EX-YRfwoRsebUkugFvht6DUPi_Q25UOCzOAqzc...'
with TelegramClient(StringSession(string), api_id, api_hash) as client:
   your code
```

you can read more in this [link](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html)